# Where to put buddypress css files

Tags: css, wordpress, buddypress

I have just installed buddypress on a wordless install and would like to create a child theme with custom styles.

I have copied the buddypress theme from plugins>buddypress>bp-templates>bp-legacy as suggested by the buddypress codex. And I have added the buddypress.css file to themes>mytheme>assets>css folder.

With the css file in that folder, the theme defaults to reading the original css file in the buddypress plugin. If I move the file out of the assets folder and into themes>mytheme>css then it reads my version of the css file, but breaks other things such as the user cover image not displaying.

Where is the correct location for buddypress.css? I am reluctant to just override the styles in style.css by using #buddypress as this will create a large css file and load the buddypress.css file from the plugin unnecessarily.

Any help will be gratefully received thanks.

Comment: I used in assets/style.css only, its overwrite perfectly. you try to load your css file below buddypress.css

Comment: Yes, this half works. Adding the css file to a 'css' folder in the root theme will override the buddypress css files in the plugin. However, the member cover photo is then broken. This appears to be added dynamically as inline css and there is clearly a path to file issue.

Comment: I think its adding by some other plugin than buddypress

Comment: I can't be added by any other plugins. I only have buddypress installed. The is a file in buddypress core files called cover-image.js which loads the inline style for cover image

Comment: OK Fine, load your CSS file in footer it will override all above styles.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much the approach I went for. I created a new file called buddypress-styles.css where all the styles start with #buddypress and added it to the header. The problem with this is that obviously the original buddypress.css file is still loaded first and consequently I have 2 http requests, one of which is unnecessary. Would be nice to find a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the buddypress css into you themes/buddypress/css folder usually you would create a css folder in your theme/buddypress then paste in the buddypress css file there.

Surely this would break your cover image. You would then need to specify a custom style for your cover image only. This can be achieved by simply dropping this code in your functionl.php file

```
function your_theme_cover_image_css( $settings = array() ) {
/**
 * If you are using a child theme, use bp-child-css
 * as the theme handel
 */
$theme_handle = 'bp-parent-css';

$settings['theme_handle'] = $theme_handle;

  /**
   * Then you'll probably also need to use your own callback function
   * @see the previous snippet
   */
   $settings['callback'] = 'bp_legacy_theme_cover_image';

   return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'bp_before_xprofile_cover_image_settings_parse_args', 
            'your_theme_cover_image_css', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'bp_before_groups_cover_image_settings_parse_args',   
'your_theme_cover_image_css', 10, 1 );
```